# Will execute time of kernel thread will be included in /proc/[pid]/stat?

Tags: kernel-modules, proc, iscsi

My process accesses a file in disk, which is mounted with iSCSI driver.
I knew iSCSI has several kernel modules and some of them run as kernel threads.

As my knowledge iSCSI needs a lot of CPU time, compared with NFS. (Reference: https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/fast04/tech/full_papers/radkov/radkov_html/head.html)

When I get a process execution time (stime+cstime from /proc/[my process's pid]/stat), will it include execution time of iSCSI kernel thread?

If not, I need to find a new way to evaluate iSCSI performance.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a command via `time` it will include `sys` and `user` times. The `system` time indicates how much time the kernel was occupied running the process. I'm not sure if you can use the `sys` time as a basis for quantifying the performance of the iSCSI driver. I personally wouldn't.

E.g.

```
time 7z b > /dev/null
real    0m32.160s
user    7m31.279s
sys     0m1.739s
```

Comment: That's a good idea. Actually, I want to add some code in source code of iSCSI kernel module and recompile it.